# How to transport a glass without breaking it

Tags: glass, moving

My family was using a normal table (6 ft * 4 ft) with a same sized glass over it. I have planned to give ONLY the glass to one of my friends as I don't need it anymore. I am going to use a double cab for the transport. I want to think about a safe way of transporting it. Since it is a square shaped, there is a chance to break the corners. Any ideas please?

Comment: Ship it with the table, then ship the table back without the glass.

Comment: Yes, it is the best solution if the table is steady, one of table legs has almost broken, so it is not a reliable way of doing that. Anyway, thanks for the idea.

Comment: You don't need the table legs. - just take the table TOP.

Tape the glass to the table if it's 'loose'. This is how you'd receive a pane of glass anyway (strapped to a shipping crate normally).

Comment: That is interesting. The only thing I need to do is remove the other three legs using a saw :-) Thanks

Comment: @KiranLinsuain If you have a solution please post it as an answer, comments shouldn't be used to answer questions

Comment: @djsmiley2k If you have a solution please post it as an answer, comments shouldn't be used to answer questions

Comment: What exactly is a "double cab"?

Comment: @JustDoIt it was someone elses answer....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the legs from the table, tape the glass TO the table to ensure it doesn't slide around.

You now have a holdable moving platform for the glass :)

Comment: Also good luck!, I'm about to move house, including 3 fishtanks and other breakables. Such fun :/

Answer (score 4):

You can buy foam boards from a hardware store. Or better, you can just ask them for scrap foam boards that they are not using, and they will most probably give it to you for free. Then you can cut indentations to fit the sides/corners into the foam board. I would suggest taping cardboard around the glass so it is less susceptible to impact.

The other thing is you can wrap the glass with towels, and ducktape them.

Answer (score 1):

Use a wooden surface with the size of the glass (or a little bigger) and attach the glass to it. You can use a sticky tape. Then wrap all this in cardboard. For extra protection you can use two wooden surfaces and put the glass between them.

If you want to protect it only from the edges then you can use only a frame to hold the glass not a whole surface. But if it is a whole wooden surface it will also protect from frontal impact.